# How to disable ripple effect when clicking in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, when you enable `clickable {}` on a modifier for a composable, by default it enables ripple effect for it. How to disable this behavior?

Example code

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
         .clickable { // action }
)
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

To disable the ripple effect, have to pass `null` to `indication` property of the modifier.

More about indication on [Jetpack Compose documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/Indication)

**Code**

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(
            indication = null, 
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() } // This is mandatory
        ) { 
            // action
        }
)
```

Comment: I get a "Cannot find a parameter with this name: indication". Am I missing something?

Comment: I believe the parameter `interactionSource` needs to come before the `indication` parameter in the list.

Comment: @JonasVautherin make sure you import the right clickable extension

Answer (score 160):

**Short answer**:
to disable the ripple pass `null` in the **`indication`** parameter in the **`clickable`** modifier:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
Column {
    Text(
        text = "Click me without any ripple!",
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = null
            ) {
                /* doSomething() */
            }
    )
```

---

**Why it doesn't work with some Composables as Buttons:**

Note that in some Composables, like `Button` or `IconButton`, it doesn't work since the `indication` is defined internally by the component which uses `indication = rememberRipple()`. This creates and remembers a `Ripple` using values provided by `RippleTheme`.

In this cases you can't disable it but you can change the appearance of the ripple that is based on a `RippleTheme`. You can define a custom RippleTheme and apply it to your composable with the `LocalRippleTheme`.

Something like:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
    Button(
        onClick = { /*...*/ },
    ) {
       //...
    }
}
```

with:

```
private object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
}
```

---

**Custom modifier**

If you prefer you can build your custom Modifier with the same code above, you can use:

```
fun Modifier.clickableWithoutRipple(
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) = composed(
    factory = {
        this.then(
            Modifier.clickable(
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = null,
                onClick = { onClick() }
            )
        )
    }
)
```

and then just apply it:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickableWithoutRipple(
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                onClick = { doSomething() }
            )
    ){ 
      //Row content
    }
```

**Long answer**:
If you add the  [**`clickable`** modifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary.html#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clickable(kotlin.Boolean,%20kotlin.String,%20androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,%20kotlin.Function0)) to a composable to make it clickable within its bounds it will show an [**`Indication`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/Indication) as specified in indication parameter.

By default, indication from [`LocalIndication`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary.html#localindication) will be used.

If you are using a `MaterialTheme` in your hierarchy, a `Ripple`, defined by **`rememberRipple()`**, will be used as the default `Indication` inside components such as `androidx.compose.foundation.clickable` and `androidx.compose.foundation.indication`.

Comment: The solution above did not seem to work when working with Buttons. See here for removing ripples from button taps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71573371/4982525

Answer (score 115):

Use this Modifier extension:

```kotlin
fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(onClick: () -> Unit): Modifier = composed {
    clickable(indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
        onClick()
    }
}
```

then simply replace `Modifier.clickable {}` with `Modifier.noRippleClickable {}`

```kotlin
Row(modifier = Modifier.noRippleClickable { 
  // action 
})
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the `Modifier` extension.

Comment: Android Studio shows warning `Unnecessary use of Modifier.composed`. Is this bug or can it be created in other way?

Comment: @iknow I don't know. There was no warning at the time I wrote this answer. Will take a look as soon as I could. Thanks for the notification.

Comment: @iknow The warning seems to have been removed as of `compose:1.2.0`

Comment: doesn't work gives me error: Backend internal error: Exception during IR lowering

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi Remove that `inline` and `crossinline` then it'll work

Comment: @BagadeshkumarR thanks it works as you said, let me post below.

Answer (score 21):

---

You can handle it this way when working with Buttons.

Create a *Ripple interactionSource* class

```
class NoRippleInteractionSource : MutableInteractionSource {

override val interactions: Flow<Interaction> = emptyFlow()

override suspend fun emit(interaction: Interaction) {}

override fun tryEmit(interaction: Interaction) = true

}
```

In case of a button, you can handle it by passing the ripple interaction class as the ***interactionSource*** parameter i.e:

```
 Button(
    onClick = { /*...*/ },
    interactionSource = NoRippleInteractionSource()
) {
    //..
}
```

This solution works with all compossables that accept a mutableInteractionSource as a parameter for example *Button()*, *TextButton()*, *Switch()*, etc

When working the clickable modifier you can do it this way:

```
modifier = Modifier.clickable(
                    indication = null,
                    interactionSource = NoRippleInteractionSource()
                ) { /** todo  action here */ }
```

You can also go a further step to modify the above answer and create an extension function and re use for all your clickable functions i.e:

```
fun Modifier.noRippleClick(onClick:()->Unit):Modifier {
  return this.clickable(
    interactionSource = NoRippleInteractionSource(),
    indication = null
   ){ 
      onClick() 
   } 
 }
```

You can now use the extension modifier in place of the clickable modifier i.e:

```
modifier = modifier.noRippleClick { /** todo  action here */  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Creates a custom Modifier that makes a Composable clickable without displaying a ripple effect when clicked.

```
fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(
     onClick: () -> Unit
): Modifier = composed {
    clickable(
        indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
        onClick()
    }
}
```

After that, you can use it like below:

```
modifier = Modifier.noRippleClickable(
                    onClick = {
                        
                    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifier extension with other parameters :

```
inline fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(
        enabled: Boolean = true,
        onClickLabel: String? = null,
        role: Role? = null,
        crossinline onClick: ()->Unit
    ): Modifier = composed {
        clickable(
            enabled = enabled,
            indication = null,
            onClickLabel = onClickLabel,
            role = role,
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
            onClick()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @Mahdi-Malv's answer and modify as below:

- remove inline and crossinline
- modify according to my requirement

> ```
> fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(
>     interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
>     indication: Indication? = null,
>     enabled: Boolean = true,
>     onClickLabel: String? = null,
>     role: Role? = null,
>     onClick: () -> Unit,
> ) = clickable(
>     interactionSource = interactionSource,
>     indication = indication,
>     enabled = enabled,
>     onClickLabel = onClickLabel,
>     role = role,
>     onClick = onClick,
> )
> ```

Comment: Doesn't work. Just copy paste this into Android studio and you'll see errors

Answer (score -2):

With `androidx.compose.foundation` there is a `enabled` attribute inside clickable extension. I think that it is easiest way. [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).clickable(androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.foundation.Indication,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.Function0))

```
fun Modifier.clickable(
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource,
    indication: Indication?,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    onClickLabel: String? = null,
    role: Role? = null,
    onClick: () -> Unit
): Modifier
```

Comment: This makes the component non-interactable (aka disabled). OP is looking to keep component interactive but remove the ripple.