# Jetpack Compose: How to disable FloatingAction Button?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button, android-compose-button

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#FloatingActionButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.material.FloatingActionButtonElevation,kotlin.Function0)), we can disable the FAB by setting `null` to its `onClick`:

> onClick - will be called when user clicked on this FAB. The FAB will
> be disabled when it is null.

When I tried it I stumbled across that the `onClick` parameter is not nullable,

[image: fabs onclick can not be null]

So, how to disable the FAB?

Comment: Just do nothing in onClick() method, like this onClick = {} . If you want to disable the ripple effect also then refer to this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703448/how-to-disable-ripple-effect-when-clicking-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: You have misunderstood the doc. Setting `onClick = null` will disable `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` not  `FloatingActionButton`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Currently (`1.x.y`) the `FloatingActionButton` doesn't support the `enabled` property.

As workaround you can use a `Button` with a `CircleShape`.

```
var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Button(
    onClick = { /* do something */},
    modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(minWidth = 56.dp, minHeight = 56.dp),
    enabled = enabled,
    shape = CircleShape

){
    Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = "Localized description")
}
```

If you want to use a `FloatingActionButton` you can do something like:

```
var enabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides
        if (enabled)  LocalRippleTheme.current else NoRippleTheme) {
    FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor = if (enabled) MaterialTheme.colors.secondary else Gray,
        onClick = { if (enabled) { /* do something */ } else {} },
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite,
            contentDescription = "Localized description",
        tint = if (enabled)
            LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
        else DarkGray)
    }
}
```

with:

```
private object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
}
```

Comment: Hope the Android Team will come up with good solution for that. But for now this is the way to go! Thanks

Comment: Is the answer still valid at the end of 2021?

Comment: @ThomasS. Yes, it is still valid.

Comment: @ThomasS. Where is the enabled Param?