# Disable ripple effect of BottomNavigationItem

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I need a bottom navigation bar for my app. To display the items I use `BottomNavigationItem`:

```kotlin
BottomNavigation(
    ...
) {
    ...
    BottomNavigationItem(
        ...
        onClick = {onItemSelect(item)},
        ...
    )
}
```

However, these come with a ripple effect that I want to disable, though I don't know how to. The `BottomNavigationItem` requires the attribute `onClick` so using the `.clickable()` modifier is not an option.

**Edit:**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66703893/14385360) from Gabriele Mariotti recommends passing a `MutableInteractionSource` to the `.clickable` function, as well as `null` for `indication`. Though `BottomNavigationItem` accepts a `MutableInteractionSource`, it does not seem to accept an `indication`.

Comment: Is that a default library? I don't find the documentation.

Comment: @MARSK I found it on the [android developer page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav). They used `BottomNavItem` as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case you can provide a custom **`LocalRippleTheme`** to override the default behaviour.

Something like:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
    BottomNavigation {
            BottomNavigationItem(
              //...
            )
        }
    }
}
```

with:

```
private object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {
    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
}
```

Comment: This is definitely more elegant than the way I found.

Comment: Error: Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option. I tried many solutions but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: A true lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

To bypass this, I copied the all BottomNavigationItem.kt file from material library and changed the line I wanted.

In box scope you can see indication parameter in selectable modifier. I pass this with null. However i can not change this parameter outside this class.

```
@Composable
fun RowScope.NoRippleEffectBottomNavigationItem(
    selected: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    icon: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    alwaysShowLabel: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    selectedContentColor: Color = LocalContentColor.current,
    unselectedContentColor: Color = selectedContentColor.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.medium)
) {
    val styledLabel: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = label?.let {
        @Composable {
            val style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
            ProvideTextStyle(style, content = label)
        }
    }
    // The color of the Ripple should always the selected color, as we want to show the color
    // before the item is considered selected, and hence before the new contentColor is
    // provided by BottomNavigationTransition.
    val ripple = rememberRipple(bounded = false, color = selectedContentColor)

    Box(
        modifier
            .selectable(
                selected = selected,
                onClick = onClick,
                enabled = enabled,
                role = Role.Tab,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = null //Changed line.
            )
            .weight(1f),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        BottomNavigationTransition(
            selectedContentColor,
            unselectedContentColor,
            selected
        ) { progress ->
            val animationProgress = if (alwaysShowLabel) 1f else progress

            BottomNavigationItemBaselineLayout(
                icon = icon,
                label = styledLabel,
                iconPositionAnimationProgress = animationProgress
            )
        }
    }
}

private val BottomNavigationAnimationSpec = TweenSpec<Float>(
    durationMillis = 300,
    easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
)

@Composable
private fun BottomNavigationTransition(
    activeColor: Color,
    inactiveColor: Color,
    selected: Boolean,
    content: @Composable (animationProgress: Float) -> Unit
) {
    val animationProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (selected) 1f else 0f,
        animationSpec = BottomNavigationAnimationSpec
    )

    val color = lerp(inactiveColor, activeColor, animationProgress)

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides color.copy(alpha = 1f),
        LocalContentAlpha provides color.alpha,
    ) {
        content(animationProgress)
    }
}

private val BottomNavigationItemHorizontalPadding = 12.dp

@Composable
private fun BottomNavigationItemBaselineLayout(
    icon: @Composable () -> Unit,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)?,
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    iconPositionAnimationProgress: Float
) {
    Layout(
        {
            Box(Modifier.layoutId("icon")) { icon() }
            if (label != null) {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .layoutId("label")
                        .alpha(iconPositionAnimationProgress)
                        .padding(horizontal = BottomNavigationItemHorizontalPadding)
                ) { label() }
            }
        }
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val iconPlaceable = measurables.first { it.layoutId == "icon" }.measure(constraints)

        val labelPlaceable = label?.let {
            measurables.first { it.layoutId == "label" }.measure(
                // Measure with loose constraints for height as we don't want the label to take up more
                // space than it needs
                constraints.copy(minHeight = 0)
            )
        }

        // If there is no label, just place the icon.
        if (label == null) {
            placeIcon(iconPlaceable, constraints)
        } else {
            placeLabelAndIcon(
                labelPlaceable!!,
                iconPlaceable,
                constraints,
                iconPositionAnimationProgress
            )
        }
    }
}

private fun MeasureScope.placeIcon(
    iconPlaceable: Placeable,
    constraints: Constraints
): MeasureResult {
    val height = constraints.maxHeight
    val iconY = (height - iconPlaceable.height) / 2
    return layout(iconPlaceable.width, height) {
        iconPlaceable.placeRelative(0, iconY)
    }
}

private val CombinedItemTextBaseline = 12.dp

private fun MeasureScope.placeLabelAndIcon(
    labelPlaceable: Placeable,
    iconPlaceable: Placeable,
    constraints: Constraints,
    /*@FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0)*/
    iconPositionAnimationProgress: Float
): MeasureResult {
    val height = constraints.maxHeight

    // TODO: consider multiple lines of text here, not really supported by spec but we should
    // have a better strategy than overlapping the icon and label
    val baseline = labelPlaceable[LastBaseline]

    val baselineOffset = CombinedItemTextBaseline.roundToPx()

    // Label should be [baselineOffset] from the bottom
    val labelY = height - baseline - baselineOffset

    val unselectedIconY = (height - iconPlaceable.height) / 2

    // Icon should be [baselineOffset] from the text baseline, which is itself
    // [baselineOffset] from the bottom
    val selectedIconY = height - (baselineOffset * 2) - iconPlaceable.height

    val containerWidth = max(labelPlaceable.width, iconPlaceable.width)

    val labelX = (containerWidth - labelPlaceable.width) / 2
    val iconX = (containerWidth - iconPlaceable.width) / 2

    // How far the icon needs to move between unselected and selected states
    val iconDistance = unselectedIconY - selectedIconY

    // When selected the icon is above the unselected position, so we will animate moving
    // downwards from the selected state, so when progress is 1, the total distance is 0, and we
    // are at the selected state.
    val offset = (iconDistance * (1 - iconPositionAnimationProgress)).roundToInt()

    return layout(containerWidth, height) {
        if (iconPositionAnimationProgress != 0f) {
            labelPlaceable.placeRelative(labelX, labelY + offset)
        }
        iconPlaceable.placeRelative(iconX, selectedIconY + offset)
    }
}
```