# Using IconButton to display a drawable in the Image using jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

This displays correctly using the `AsyncImage`. But I would like to use it in a `IconButton`, but the affect is different. See below for `IconButton` with an `Image`

```
 AsyncImage(
                    model = R.drawable.add_photo,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.selected_image),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(60.dp)
                        .border(
                            width = 2.dp,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.photoPickerBorderColor,
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                        )
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)).
                        clickable {
                            onAddPhotosClicked()
                        })
```

And I am trying to use the `IconButton` here with an `Image` with the same properties, just wondering why does it display like this, as it seems to be clipping the corners. Is there anyway to display it like in the `AsyncImage`

[image]

```
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                onAddPhotosClicked()
            }) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.add_photo),
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.add_photos),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(60.dp)
                    .border(
                        width = 2.dp,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.photoPickerBorderColor,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)
                    )
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp)),
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because M3 icon button clips with `md.sys.shape.corner.full` which is a circle as can be in [official document](https://m3.material.io/components/icon-buttons/specs#fbe6913b-2c1b-42c1-be4a-3d73d9dc601d).

And the source code of IconButton for M3, you can see for M2 in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266036/5457853)

```
@Composable
fun IconButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    colors: IconButtonColors = IconButtonDefaults.iconButtonColors(),
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .minimumInteractiveComponentSize()
            .size(IconButtonTokens.StateLayerSize)
            .clip(IconButtonTokens.StateLayerShape.toShape())
            .background(color = colors.containerColor(enabled).value)
            .clickable(
                onClick = onClick,
                enabled = enabled,
                role = Role.Button,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = rememberRipple(
                    bounded = false,
                    radius = IconButtonTokens.StateLayerSize / 2
                )
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        val contentColor = colors.contentColor(enabled).value
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides contentColor, content = content)
    }
```

You can easily copy source code and remove clip or create your own `Box` with similar properties.