# Disabling Ripple Effect in Modifier.clickable Using CompositionLocalProvide

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to disable the ripple effect for Modifier.clickable, so I used CompositionLocalProvider. However, it doesn't work on some devices. How can I solve this issue?

Example Code

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
  LocalRippleTheme provides ClearRippleTheme
) {
  App24hMainView()
}
```

```
object ClearRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor(): Color = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha() = RippleAlpha(
        draggedAlpha = 0.0f,
        focusedAlpha = 0.0f,
        hoveredAlpha = 0.0f,
        pressedAlpha = 0.0f
    )
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66703448/18058213 similar question, might be useful

Comment: I've read this article, but what I'm looking for is a way to make comprehensive changes all at once, without adding Modifier extensions or creating an interactionSource. Using these two methods would require too many replacements